# Fields for PostgreSQL Stats Monitoring Service - Transactions/sec, Batch Request/sec, and Buffer Cache Hit Ratio

Tags: postgresql, performance, .net-core

I am currently working on a service to monitor and collect statistics for a PostgreSQL database, but I seem to be unable to find the data for the following crucial fields:

1. Transactions/sec
2. Batch Request/sec
3. Buffer Cache Hit Ratio

I have extensively searched through the PostgreSQL documentation and explored various system views and functions such as pg_stat_database, pg_stat_bgwriter, and others, but I couldn't locate these specific metrics.

Could anyone with experience in PostgreSQL database monitoring shed some light on where I can find or calculate these missing fields? Is there a particular system view or a different approach I should be using to gather this data?

Edit:
In Microsoft SQL Server, I am familiar with using the dynamic management view (DMV) to access these metrics easily. However, I am struggling to locate the corresponding fields or views in PostgreSQL.